# Angular 7 getting value of selected date from Kendo UI date picker

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-components, kendo-ui-angular2, angular-component-life-cycle

My App Component.html has a basic navigation and a date picker, like so...

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

<!-- Navigation Removed -->          
        <div class="col-md-2 float-right">
            <kendo-datepicker
                (valueChange)="onChange($event)"
                [(value)]="value">
            </kendo-datepicker>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The component.ts is set up in the following way:

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  @Input() value: Date = new Date();
  @Output() dateChanged: EventEmitter<Date> = new EventEmitter<Date>();

  constructor() {}

  public onChange(value: Date): void {
    this.dateChanged.emit(value);
  }
}
```

I've got some pages that have a grid control calling a service, but the date is currently hard-coded, and this all works fine.  I want the ability to refresh the grid data based on the selected date from the above date picker, essentially, I will click on the datapicker, the emitted value will be passed to a method in the component with the grid controller.

Controller with Grid:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { GridDataResult, DataStateChangeEvent } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';
import { DataSourceRequestState } from '@progress/kendo-data-query';
import { DataService } from '../services/DataService.service';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { State } from '@progress/kendo-data-query';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './grid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./grid.component.css']
})
export class GridComponent implements OnInit {

  public products: GridDataResult;
  public state: DataSourceRequestState = {
      skip: 0,
      take: 25
  };
  @Input() value: Date = new Date();

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.dataService.fetch(this.state).subscribe(r => this.products = r);
  }

  public dataStateChange(state: DataStateChangeEvent): void {
    this.state = state;
    this.dataService.fetch(state)
        .subscribe(r => this.products = r);
}

}
```

Comment: Where is your grid controller? Is it a service, or another component? Currnetly you are outputting `dateChanged` from `AppComponent` which seems to be your main component, where do you listen this emitted event?

Comment: @CeritT, I have added the controller with the Grid

Comment: Why don't you use the OnChanges Lifecycle hook to listen for an incoming date on your grid component. The question you asked is 'How to Get the Value out of Kendo UI DatePicker' but I think your real problem is listening for an input change to make a new dataService call.

Comment: @CMR, this sounds correct - are you suggesting the same approach as CeritT suggested below?

Comment: @christiandev , No CeritT is suggesting to create a service and expose the Kendo Data Change as an observable that you can subscribe to in your grid component. This would 100% work, but it looks to me you already have the Date Input on your grid class, so what you really need is a way to detect when that input changes so you can refresh the grid, which is why I recommended the OnChanges lifecycle hook. I could give you a more formal answer if you wish.

Comment: @CMR, that would be great - I kind of understand how that works in a parent-child relationship, but I can't seem to apply it here.  Any help would be great.

Comment: @christiandev, so I started looking at your issue a little more in detail, and I realized that OnChanges WILL not work for you. You are trying to go across a `router-outlet` and parent/child communication does not work across `router-outlet`. So you will have to create a service like CeritT recommended. He does a good job explaining this, but if you have any questions, feel free to reach out. I use Angular/Kendo everyday for my work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Subject` to listen changes on your date input.

First create a date service.

```
@Injectable()
export class DateService {

  public chosenDate: Observable<Date>;
  private dateSubject: Subject<Date>;

  constructor() {
    this.dateSubject = new Subject<Date>();
    this.chosenDate = this.dateSubject.asObservable();
  }

  dateChanged(newDate:Date){
    this.dateSubject.next(newDate);
  }

}
```

Then in your Grid Controller, inject this service and subscribe to chosen date from service where you need in your component.

```
constructor(private service: DateService){
```

```
this.service.chosenDate.subscribe((date: Date) => { 
    // do something useful with date
});
```

and finally on your date field change event, put this code to pass new date to the service

```
this.service.dateChanged(date);
```

Edit: Here I made an example for you, demonstrating the solution. I'm sure you can easilty implement this in your code.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-4durfi)

Comment: Thanks - I will try this today.

Comment: Hi @christiandev, i couldn't have time to check SO lately, how things worked out for you? Did you give it a try?

Comment: Yes, I have just got it working - many thanks.  I'm just looking a the best way to set a default value for the date until a date is selected now.

Comment: You can initialize `date` property, `date:Date = new Date();` in your grid controller. And use [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) to format it as you need.